# Unable to Append Child in JavaScript using appendChild

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to append some html which is coming as a string in a div but some how `appendChild` is not working as expected here is my JS code:

```
var doc = document.getElementById("products");
var notes = doc.getElementsByClassName("product_grid");


var str = '<div>New Node 3<div><div>New Node 4<div>';

var child = document.createElement('div');
child.innerHTML = str;
child = child.firstChild;
notes.appendChild(child);
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="products" >
    <div class="product_grid">
        <div>
            Existing node 1
            <div>
        <div>
            Existing node 2
            <div>                
    </div>
</div>
```

What is wrong with it its unable to Identify the appendChild as a function and keeps giving me error `TypeError: notes.appendChild is not a function` here is [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/af4ZT/)

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection (note the plural `getElements...`), rather than a single node. And, the collection itself doesn't support `.appendChild()`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks mate i just noticed it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`notes` is a `NodeList`. So you'll have to use index to select the elements.

Try this:

```
notes[0].appendChild(child); // Appends to first product_grid
```

Comment: Great Thanks mate :D jeez i was missing the index. I will make it a right answer when time limit will be gone

Comment: @PHPSeeker glad to have helped you :)